# How to do profile pages like: /1234? (No "#" and no "?id=")

Tags: php, javascript

I want to do profile pages in my site. Right now are identified with a hash such as:

```
www.mysite.com/#123123
```

However I noticed that sites like Facebook or Twitter use URLs such as: facebook.com/1234 to identify profiles.

How can I do this on my site?

Comment: This is done with a URL rewriting engine like Apache mod_rewrite.  The rewrite engine matches a regular expression, and may pass a portion of the URL (the number in this case) to the PHP file as a `$_GET` parameter without redirecting the user's browser to reflect that.

Comment: [Many of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+id) will get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but depending on your controller, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
##Do rewrite if NOT file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
##Do rewrite if NOT dir/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

##Numeric
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
##Or for AlphaNumeric (any case)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]

##Or for Anything after first slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L] 
##Note using this method you would need a (Router) controller that splits
## the request.
##Eg site.com/id/Af13s passes index.php?route=id/Af13s then with
## explode('/',$_GET['route']) you can get the action/sub action 

##or have multiple entry's for each section
RewriteRule ^id/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ admin.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How can I make it work even when the ID is non-numeric without having conflicts with subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely they are using .htaccess or similar to redirect the /1234 to some script like profile.php?id=1234

To answer your question better, look into mod_rewrite.  Also, [this](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) might be of help, particularly the "Create beautiful URLs" section.